# Automatic translation from Isabelle/HOL to HOL

Tags: isabelle, hol

I have some definitions and theorems in Isabelle/HOL and need to use those same definitions and theorems with HOL. Translating the code manually is certainly possible, but cumbersome. Are there any programs that (semi-)automatically perform such a translation?

If this is not possible for some reason, please explain why, since this would be an important learning for me.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you should be able to easily move theorems and definitions between HOL implementations, and this idea is the motivation of the [OpenTheory](http://www.gilith.com/opentheory/) project.  Unfortunately, in practice, Isabelle's implementation of HOL is sufficiently different from the others, and per the OpenTheory page Isabelle only has the ability to import theorems using OpenTheory, and cannot export them, at present.